# How would you create table statement for this er diagram?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

[image]

**Which attributes would be in the placement table?**

How would you write the create table statement if it is one to one relationship? Would this be correct

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have x and y in the Placement Table and the sid. I would do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Placement (
  pid int NOT NULL,
  is_critical bool,
  PRIMARY KEY (pid),
  FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hold(hid),
  FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES Route(rid),
  FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Slot(sid));
```

Comment: Why would the pid be necessary? Can the primary key be a combination of hid, rid, sid?

Comment: Pid isn't necessary, but you should have a primary key. A Combination of hid, rid and sid could also be a primary key